# I want to change remote git url to example2.git in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, .git-folder

Here i am attaching my problem. I want my repository to be hairbodyskin-production. But it is not changing. It should not be cw-community.

[image]

I tried this `

```
git config remote.origin.url https://x-token-auth:ATCTT3xFfGN02teIasCShaVu_OFcBiXmEGz5eXTLrjSOrRtyaZt-OU3r0II2rUS58_5auPxITl-L7aEVEge-aCHSUOZI4Cl0fgEtHSAzgX9Gg75Zrn2_pC1s7966yjgp4M1n0IshRyjKkleqGl2rxttxe6gbaHbCExkW0gbSDzc2Z4JgZlqlSoM\=65CB674A@bitbucket.org/cwdevelop/hairbodyskin-production.git
```

I also tried this

```
git config remote.origin.url --global https://x-token-auth:ATCTT3xFfGN02teIasCShaVu_OFcBiXmEGz5eXTLrjSOrRtyaZt-OU3r0II2rUS58_5auPxITl-L7aEVEge-aCHSUOZI4Cl0fgEtHSAzgX9Gg75Zrn2_pC1s7966yjgp4M1n0IshRyjKkleqGl2rxttxe6gbaHbCExkW0gbSDzc2Z4JgZlqlSoM\=65CB674A@bitbucket.org/cwdevelop/hairbodyskin-production.git
```

`I also tried this

```
git remote set-url origin https://x-token-auth:ATCTT3xFfGN02teIasCShaVu_OFcBiXmEGz5eXTLrjSOrRtyaZt-OU3r0II2rUS58_5auPxITl-L7aEVEge-aCHSUOZI4Cl0fgEtHSAzgX9Gg75Zrn2_pC1s7966yjgp4M1n0IshRyjKkleqGl2rxttxe6gbaHbCExkW0gbSDzc2Z4JgZlqlSoM\=65CB674A@bitbucket.org/cwdevelop/hairbodyskin-production.git
```

Nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you might have set your remote URL in the git global config file.

Checkout this post to see if the steps there are able to resolve your problem.

[Using 'git remote add origin' creates a global remote instead of one local to current directory/repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369704/using-git-remote-add-origin-creates-a-global-remote-instead-of-one-local-to-cu)